# Computing phase angle in fft matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, atan2

I am trying to compute the phase angle in the frequency domain (after computing fft) of the second component of the Fourier spectrum of a synthetic signal constructed by me in the workspace of Matlab. I am sure that the phase is equal to 0 (as you can see in the code), but the result I get is pi/2. The code is the following:

```
t = 0:pi / 128:(2 * pi - pi / 128);
V = sin(t);
L = length(V);
n = 2^nextpow2(L);
Y = fft(V, n);
threshold = max(abs(Y))/10000;
Y(abs(Y)<threshold) = 0;
mag = abs(Y/n);
angle = rad2deg(atan2(imag(Y),real(Y)));
```

I do not see where the error is.

Comment: Why are you sure that the phase is zero?

Comment: Taking into account the standard sine wave (A*sin(wt+phi), where A is the amplitude, w is the frequency in radians, and phi is the initial phase), the phase of the signal in line 2 is zero.

Comment: Ah, I see the original sequence is periodic with the DFT length. I added an answer - does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken that the phase of a real, periodic *sine* wave with a frequency that corresponds to the bin center frequency (and no phase offset) is zero. The basis functions representing the *real* part of the original sequence are cosine functions.

To represent a sine wave with a cosine wave a phase offset of pi/2 has to be subtracted:

sin(x) = cos(x - pi/2).

Therefore, the phase in bin 2 (corresponding to the frequency of the original sequence), is -pi/2.

(For a more thorough explanation see [this question on DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30436/what-does-it-mean-for-the-dft-phase-to-be-relative-to-a-cosine-wave).)

Comment: Yes, your response answers my question. Thank you very much!